# Auto correct phone format input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm trying to auto format an input on HTML with javascript, and it is almost done, i need the format to be xxx-xxx-xxxx but and I have this code

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/(\d{3})\-?/g,'$1-');
```

as youy can see it will just auto format xxx-xxx-xxx but I need to be 4 digits at the end

any sugestions?

Answer (score 4):

Try this regexp:

```
'1234567890'.replace(/(\d{3}(?!\d?$))\-?/g, '$1-'); // 123-456-7890
```

The part `(?!\d?$)` is a negative lookahead. It allows regular expression to match three digits only if they are not followed by another number (4th) (but not necessarily `?`) at the end of the string `$`.

So it will not match `789` group because it's followed by `0$`.

Comment: awsome, that was what i needed

Answer (score 2):

Or simply : .`replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})\-?/g,'$1-$2-$3');`

Comment: Indeed, pretty simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

Sample code to help you out:

```
var phone = '(555) 666-7777';

// First clean your input
phone = phone.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
// Check the length of the phone
if(phone.length == 10){
    // Now we can format the phone
    phone = phone.substring(0,3)+'-'+phone.substring(3,6)+'-'+phone.substring(6, 10);
    // Optionally
    //phone = phone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})/, '$1-$2-');
}
else {
    // whatever you want to tell the user
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there seems to be a bug in the "replace" regex's above.  enter a 10 digit number and you see it formatted correctly (e.g. "(123) 456-7890").  Then, select the contents of the field (double or triple click it) and overtype the value.  You'll see the first two digits get transposed.  So if you enter 1 2 3, you'll see 2 1 3...

Comment: Hi there, welcome to S-O. This should be a comment on the question as it's not actually an answer.